# Looping Perl Array

Tags: perl

I'm creating a little program that takes an array and returns it randomly, problem being I'm not sure I understand how to return an array randomly sorted in Perl. I want this array to return randomly 50 times:

```
 x @array = ("O", "I", "S", "Z", "L", "J", "T")
 print x @array = rand(@array);
```

As you can see I've tried a rand function, but it gives me this error on the output:

> Array found where operator expected at random.pl lone 1, at end of     line syntax error at random.pl line 1, near "x@array" Execution of
> random.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

If anybody could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably lose both `x`'s.  You should put a semicolon after the array line.  Then you probably want a random number in the range 0..6 (you'll need to convert it to an interger), and you'll use that as an index into your array.  `perldoc -f rand` should tell you how `rand` works.  There are endless ways to loop 50 times (well, there are a large number of such ways, but they all come to an end after the fiftieth iteration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `shuffle` function from [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) to randomly sort the elements of your array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my @array = ("O", "I", "S", "Z", "L", "J", "T");
for (1..5) {
    print join ' ', shuffle(@array), "\n";
}

__END__

T J Z O S I L 
L Z I O S J T 
I O J Z T S L 
J O I Z L S T 
O I Z T S J L
```